# Combine Stripe Subscribe and Connect in one stage

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there a way for me as a platform to sign someone up to a subscription plan (my customer) then also authenticate them with connect.stripe so that they are a connected account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. Subscriptions with Stripe are associated with a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api?#customers) object, which is entirely distinct from an [Account](https://stripe.com/docs/api?#account) object representing a Connected Account.

You can certainly create a customer object and an account object, and then store the two IDs (`cus_xxx`) and (`acct_xxx`) together in your own system to link them together as the same person, but there is no linkage in Stripe's API for this relationship.